# Import txt file into my database with specific format

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL and I searched internet. Before I used CSV file or SQL file to import my data into DB. But now I have a text file with this format:

```
number  
989399999999    
989388888888    
989384444444
```

This continues about 300 records. How can I import this to my database?

Comment: If it has only 1 column, it is already CSV, also TabSV, etc :)

Comment: and dont need any line terminator?

Comment: If it is multiline, then it already has a line terminator. Of course it doesn't have a *field* terminator, because there is only 1 field. Unless I misunderstood something. You can choose a random field terminator.

Comment: ok so the only thing should i do is that save this file by csv format and import it to my db ?yeah ?

Comment: You can directly import it in this format, but using the CSV import options…

Answer (score 1):

[`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/load-data.html)

> The LOAD DATA INFILE statement reads rows from a text file into a
>   table at a very high speed. The file name must be given as a literal
>   string.

`LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Users\\hi\\Desktop\\abc.txt' INTO TABLE customer LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 LINES`

Query is self explanatory I hope :)